# Welcome messages and goodbye messages not working discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot and I would like to make it have commands, and events. For the sake of this I will just show you the joined and left messages. I have a on_member_join event and on_member_remove event. Here is my code:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$") #From discord.ext I imported commands

#---WELCOME MESSAGE---

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = client.get_guild(886429978751807520)
  channel = guild.get_channel(897989215483220008)
  await channel.send(f"""
  Welcome to MM Gang, {member.mention}! :partying_face:

For some information about the server check this out! <#{886432817511297074}>
Check out the Server's Rules! <#{886430551681163264}>
Get some roles! <#{886433467024416819}>
If you have anymore questions ask them here! <#{886675207467696138}>

That's it, hope you have fun!
""")

#---GOODBYE MESSAGE---

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  guild = client.get_guild(886429978751807520)
  channel = guild.get_channel(897989215483220008)
  await channel.send(f"""
  {member.mention} has just left the server! :cry:
  """)
```

For some reason this is not working. If you know the problem please let me know, it would help me out a bunch!

Comment: BTW, I did not include this but I have imported discord, os, and I made the bot run 24/7. I just showed the joiend or left messages.

Comment: Are you using the correct intents?

Comment: Assuming the bot is attached to the correct server, and the intents are correct. We need to figure out if the event is triggered. Add a print. If it is in fact triggered then we need to make sure the guild/channel are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use Embeds, I think it might help

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    lol = timestamp.strftime(r"%I:%M %p")
    guild_id = member.guild.id
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_server_id)
    logs = client.get_channel(logs_channel_id)
    mc = guild.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member}",
                          description=f"{member.mention} has joined the server!",
                          colour=discord.Colour.green())
    embed.add_field(name="User ID:",
                    value=member.id,
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Member count:",
                    value=mc,
                    inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{timestamp}•{lol}")
    await logs.send(embed=embed)
```

You will need to change things, but for me it works
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create%20text%20channel#discord.on_member_join

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).